# hibernate or oracle support for timelines?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, orm

We have a requirement for persisting, using Hibernate, versioned Java objects into an Oracle database such that each version has a valid-from and valid-until timestamp. This is so we can query for objects as-at a specific time.

Does Hibernate or Oracle 11g (or anything else) provide anything that would simplify this?

Comment: both flashback and envers are possible solutions, but I can't accept both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Hibernate Envers](http://www.jboss.org/envers)

> The Envers project aims to enable easy auditing/**versioning of persistent classes**. All that you have to do is annotate your persistent class or some of its properties, that you want to audit, with @Audited. For each audited entity, a table will be created, which will hold the history of changes made to the entity. **You can then retrieve and query historical data** without much effort.

Comment: Looking at the documentation for this, I can see that you can select a given revision, but I can't see where you can select using an as-at date.

Answer (score 3):

If you have Oracle Enteprise Edition you can create a flashback archive for the table(s) in question, and then using plain SQL you can do a `SELECT * FROM table_name AS OF timestamp`

Oracle will manage everything in the background for your once the flashback archive has been created.

Some more details are in the manual:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/adfns/flashback.html#GUID-CAC23AAE-AD5A-47FA-B446-B4DE00B2B876